# Dreamweaver cs6 and SCSS

Tags: dreamweaver, sass

I can't make my Dreamweaver CS6 to load sass (SCSS) files as css (it won't color it).
It was working fine on CS5.5 version. Now I have fresh DW CS6 with all updates (12.0.3) and I have modified all needed files. 
Instruction is [here](http://blog.assortedgarbage.com/2012/03/using-dreamweaver-with-sass-and-less/) or [here](http://tracehello.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/making-dreamweaver-cs5-read-scss-as-css/).

DW still won't apply coloring to my code and when (while open scss file) I go to preferences --> code coloring, Document type highlighted is Text.

Any ideas? Maybe there are another files in CS6 I have to modify?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. In CS6 in addition to the files listed in both tutorial (linked in the question), there is one more file that needs to be changed.
It's **MMDocumentTypes.xml** located in AppData files here:

**C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6\en_US\Configuration\DocumentTypes**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Dreamweaver CS6.

I had to update the files in my **hidden** Library folder

First enable finder to show hidden files.

Open a terminal and paste the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Restart Terminal:

Keep “Alt” key pressed, put mouse over “Finder icon” – your app bar and “right click”. A menu appear and click on “Relaunch”

1. Open Finder and go to “your folder”
2. Go to (open folder by folder) Library. Application Support, Adobe, Dreamweaver CS6, en_US,
   Configuration
3. Edit the Extentions.txt and DocumentTypes/MMDocumentTypes.xml files there.
4. Restart Dreamweaver and you should be good to go.

Update your terminal to hide hidden files

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
```

Full instructions are from here:
http://www.fastinfo.com.au/dreamever-syntax-highlight-for-less-and-sass/